# Oracle - Aren't stored procedures preferred to in-application queries?

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, oracle10g, delphi-2010

I've always heard and believed that stored procedures are the heart of an SQL database and they're the most optimal objects to use for many purposes. Many people even use stored procedures instead of triggers. In my Delphi application I query a table with 20.000+ rows, each row consisting of about 20 columns. When I do this with stored procedure it takes about 3 seconds to load but if I use queries it takes less than a second. This is very important because the table is going to hold more that a million records. I need to choose the best optimal way as I'm convinced that it will never be less than 10 seconds when the table is full with that many records. How come a stored procedure takes longer than ad hoc queries.

Comment: Beware of triggers... they make an application less maintenable. If you need multiple tables/rows update in a single call, a stored procedure is far better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedures are generally preferred because they promote better code organization and because they make it much easier for DBAs and database developers to optimize the code.  There should be no difference in performance, however, if your stored procedure is simply opening and returning a `SYS_REFCURSOR` compared to an application issuing an identical SQL statement.

- Is your query just opening a `SYS_REFCURSOR` and returning it?  Or is it doing something else?
- Are both queries using bind variables?  Or is one using literals instead?
- Are you getting the same query plan for both approaches?
- Are you fetching the same number of rows in both cases?  Or are you potentially just fetching the first N rows when you issue the direct SQL statement and fetching all the rows when you use the stored procedure?

Comment: Your last point helped me find the problem. Yes, I actually was not fetching all the rows at once when using UniQuery component, but when using UniStoredProc I was fetching all the rows at once. The default FetchRows property is 25, which I did not change in the query component. Now, after tweaking this I get even faster result with the stored procedure. Thank you all so much

Answer (score 4):

Always you must prefear use stored procedures  to do the heavy work , because have many advatages like run in the server side and use the server resources (Fast HDD, CPU and Memory), reduces the network traffic usage  . For example if you need to make a complicated calculation over a big set of records you can write an stored procedure to resolve the task instead of retrieve the Dataset and process yourself in the aplication.

Note: when you say `...In my Delphi application I query a table with 20.000+ rows` I really hope that you are not bringing the +20.000 records to your application because that is not effective method (instead you must filter your records adding a Where clause with the appropriate conditions or you can use a pagination method)

Now about you particular issue some thoughts

- ORACLE have a [cached execution](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=503) facility where the Query is hashed and stored to improve the execution. Maybe your query is using this feature.
- Another alternative is which the speed of your query is faster than the stored procedure  due maybe you are using a **forward only dataset** component which only retrieve a small set of the records at once.

For give you alternatives you must provide more information , like the SQL components which you are using, a sample sql sentence and indicate if you are retrieving all the records to your aplication.

Comment: I use DevaArt's UniDac component suite to work with Oracle. Actually there are about 190.000 records in my table I just query for 20.000 of them. My SQL Sencetence is "SELECT * FROM PENSIONERS WHERE DEPARTID=118". I do not use star (*) in the select list, instead I provide all the column names as I know that using star impacts performance.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Oracle for over 8 Years now and the following works really well to manage performance, I have several tables that have more than a millions rows:

- Use stored procedures for Logic that involves operations on the data.
- Use Select statements when viewing the data, without stored procedures.     I have better things to do than to create another layer in my application that offers no benefits.
- Use Bind Variables in your SQL Statements, Oracle caches all statements, but if you use bind variables it's more efficient.
- Look at the [explain plan](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:231814117467) of your Queries, makes sure you have the *correct* indexes in place to avoid full table scans on your large tables as they can slow down performance.   Note that too many indexes on a table can also slow down update and insert performance.
- Indexes with Oracle can call functions for example we commonly don't care about time in a date field so our indexes are `create index idxname on tablename(trunc(datefield));`
- When building apps with large tables **NEVER** consider returning all the row to the application.     Build a screen that allows your users to search the data for the records desired.     The network IO alone makes a design that returns all the rows a bad idea.
- The oracle [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com) website has several articles on performance and [SQL Tuning](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:8764517459743).

Comment: Oracle will cache *any statement* to avoid an hard parse if it is reused. Flooding the database with many different queries that differ only for what should be "bind variables" is a good way to make that cache inefficient. A different CURSOR_SHARING value can be used as a workaround, but SP or bind variables are a better choice.
SP may offer benefits even for SELECTs (i.e. better security...), but those benefits should be weighted against the need to mantain them.
Full table scans are not always evil, and index are not always good. See Tom Kyte blog (or books) for a full explanation.